# How to add ssml in suggestion chips actions on google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, ssml

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.ask(`Your device is not compatible`);
    return;
  }
  conv.ask(`It's a rhyming word game app. A Random word will be given to you. You have to enter a rhyming word against it. if you are ready to play? press the button below`);
  conv.ask(new Suggestions([`Start Game`, `Exit`]));
});
```

Comment: I want my assistant to speak suggestions chips as well. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion chips are meant to be hints for what the user will say, not something that your Action says. As such, using SSML in the suggestion chips wouldn't be expected.

If you want the suggestions to be read out, they should be placed alongside the text that your Action is outputting.

Comment: I am asking for google home speaker devices. Suppose If I am building an app for both platforms google assistant and google home. For a google home user, how would they know there is a suggestion chip? Or do I need to write separate code for both devices?

Comment: Suggestion chips are not necessarily meant to be replacements for user input. I would suggest checking the [surface capabilities](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities) and changing your text-to-speech if the surface does not have a screen.